# Flask doesn't load css correctly

Tags: python, html, css, flask

I'm working with Flask and everything is going well until I created another path and the stylesheet didn't load.

The stylesheet is in the static folder and everything but I can't get it to load.

It works perfectly for the routes on first routes after home e.g. `("/home" ,  "/index", "/dashboard")`. It removes the styles when it goes into secondary routes e.g. `("/home/first", "/index/first")`

Comment: are you getting 404 In the flask log? also pls provide the actual code and folder structure screen view.

Answer (score 0):

make sure the file extends the base or whatever file that contains the link to the css styling

```py
{% extends "template_that_links_to_css.py" %}
```

Answer (score 0):

> The most powerful part of Jinja is template inheritance. Template inheritance allows you to build a base “skeleton” template that contains all the common elements of your site and defines blocks that child templates can override.

For example:

```html
<!-- base.html -->

{% extends 'bootstrap/base.html' %}

{% block styles %}
    {{ super() }}
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='css/styles.css') }}">
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
    <!-- your child templates will go here -->
{% endblock %}
```

This base template inherits the styles from `flask-bootstrap` to begin with. Then it defines the link to the `styles.css` file. All child templates' content will come within the `block content`. So regardless of what template you create, as long as it inherits this base template, your styles defined in `styles.css` will always apply.

A child template, say `index.html`, which is rendered when the `home()` view function is called will look like this:

```html
<!-- index.html-->

{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
           <!-- content -->
        </div>
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

You inherit the base template using the keyword `extends`. As mentioned ealier, the content will appear in the `block content` of the base template, so this has to be defined explictly.

The route to render this page can look like this:

```py
# routes.py

from app import app
from flask import render_template

@app.route("/home")
def home():
    return render_template("index.html")
```

So, regardless of whatever template you create, as long as you are inheriting the base template, your styles will apply in each one of them.

Read more from [template inheritance doc](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/patterns/templateinheritance/).